# Beanshell Scripting in Jmeter

Tags: java, scripting, jmeter, performance-testing, beanshell

### I am trying to increment an alphanumeric string and pass that to a request in Jmeter 2.11. Attaching the snippet below. Please help.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

var str="BaseDS66";
var a=1;
int position=8;
String newStr=str.substring(6,position);
//String newStr=str.replace("BaseDS","");
var n = ${newStr};
//String ADD = newStr + Integer.parseInt(1);
//String newStr1=sum(newStr + a);
//for (int i=0; i<newStr )
vars.put("Str",n);
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to :

1. Extract this `66`
2. Increment it to `67`
3. Replace the original value so `BaseDS66` becomes `BaseDS67`
4. And store the value into `${Str}` JMeter Variable you can do it as follows:

   ```
   import java.util.regex.Matcher;
   import java.util.regex.Pattern;

   String str = "BaseDS66";

   Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\d+)", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.DOTALL);
   Matcher m = p.matcher(str);

   if (m.find()) {
       String originalValueString = m.group(1);
       int originalValue = Integer.parseInt(originalValueString);
       originalValue++;
       String newStr = str.replace(originalValueString, String.valueOf(originalValue));
       log.info("Incremented value: " + newStr);
       vars.put("Str", newStr);
   }
   ```

Demo:

[image: Regex Increment JMeter]

References:

- [Lesson: Regular Expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/)
- [Class Pattern](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)
- [How to Use BeanShell: JMeter's Favorite Built-in Component](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell)